# about symmetric and hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Using the frobenius norm $\langle A,B\rangle=\textrm{Tr}(B^{\star}A)$, where $B^{\star}=\overline{(B^T)}$, How can I prove that $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{C})^{\perp}=A\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{C})$, that is that the orthogonal complement from the set of the symmetric matrices is the set of skew-symmetric matrices.

And, I know that for this inner product, isn't true, that $\mathbb{H}(\mathbb{C})^{\perp}=A\mathbb{H}(\mathbb{C})$, that is, that the orthogonal complement from the set of hermitian matrices, is the set of skew-hermitian matrices, but there exists an inner product where the fact above is true.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that a skew matrix is orthogonal to a symmetric matrix (this is obvious, just write down the inner product). Then note that the dimensions of the set of symmetric matrices and skew matrices are complementary. I can't understand your comment about hermitian matrices, but the same argument should confirm or deny that this is true for them.

**EDIT** For Hermitian matrices ,the condition is that $a_{ij} \overline{b_{ij}} - \overline{a_{ij}} b_{ij} = 0,$ for every $i, j.$ This quantity is the *imaginary* part of $a_{ij} \overline{b_{ij}}.$ So, the inner product you are looking for is $i \mathop{trace} (A B^H).$

Comment: Thank you, the thing about hermitian matrices is that whit this inner product (frobenius norm) we have not the case that the one is the orthogonal complement, but there exists and inner product that makes this assertion truth, i have to create this product, but I don't know how

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: @IgorRivin, I do not believe that the "inner product" you described is in fact an inner product. Assume on the contrary that it is. Then $$ \overline{\langle B, A\rangle} = \overline{i tr(B A^H)} = -i \overline{tr(BA^H)}. $$ But, $$ \langle A,B \rangle = i tr(AB^H) = i tr((BA^H)^H) = i \overline{ tr(BA^H)} = -\overline{\langle B,A\rangle}, $$ so the inner product is skew conjugate-symmetric, not conjugate-symmetric as required.